# Proof for Lemma about convex hull

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to prove a Lemma: "**For the set B of all convex combinations of arbitrary finite number of points from set A, $co (A)=B$**"

I started by showing $B\subset co(A)$ first. 
$B$ contains all convex combinations of arbitrary finite number of points from A.
Let $x=\alpha_1 x_1 +...+\alpha_n x_n$ be convex combination of $x_1,...x_n\in A$
$x\in B$
Let $C$ be any convex set that contains A.
Now I know that $x_1,...,x_n\in C$ and, since $C$ is convex, it contains all convex combinations of arbitrary finite number of its points (and points from A), so $x\in C$.
Thus, $B\subset C$
I also know that $C=co(C)$ because $C$ is convex.
Also, $A\subset C \rightarrow co(A)\subset co(C) \rightarrow co(A)\subset C$

So I have $B\subset C$ and $co(A)\subset C$.
How can I conclude from this that $B\subset co(A)$?

What about another direction, $co(A)\subset B$? Just to prove that $B$ is convex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start with the set $B$ you mentioned. Clearly, $A\subset B$. The tricky part here is to show that $B$ is a convex set (needs a little work but surely you can do it). Using the definition of convex hull, it follows that 
$$\operatorname{co}(A)\subset B.$$

Next, for any arbitrary convex set $C$ with $A\subset C$, then as what you have said, $B\subset C$. Hence 
$$B\subset\bigcap_{A\subset C}C=\operatorname{co}(A).$$

Comment: Can you explain to me why $B\subset\bigcap_{A\subset C}C$ ?

Comment: I do not think that $B \subset C$ is correct where $C$ is any convex set containing $A$.

Comment: @juniven Your proof has a mistake as I pointed out above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the correct phrasing? As it stands, I think you can only say the convex hull of $A$ is contained in $B$.

For instance, think about $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $A = \{(0,0)\}$, whilst $B$ is the $x$-axis. Then surely $B$ contains all convex combinations of the points in $A$, but it's not the convex hull.

Comment: It's not MY conclusion. It is a Theorem. 

Ok, let's say that $B$ is a set of all convex combinations of arbitrary finite number of points from $A$.  
If $x\in B$, then $x$ is a convex combination of elements from $A$.  
Since $A\subset co(A)$, which is closed and contains all convex combinations of finite number of elements from A, that means that $x\in co(A)$.
  
Now, if $x,y\in B, x=\sum^{m}_{k=1} \alpha_k x_k, y=\sum^{n}_{k=1} \beta_k y_k$ it is not difficult to show that $\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y \in B$, which would mean that B is convex.

Comment: I don't have it. Can I find it on internet in pdf?

Comment: @juniven I don't have a book that you mentioned, but I have another one. And I found this theorem and a proof on internet too. But they say that this is wrong. If you have that book, can you tell me is this wrong or not?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9113/discussion-between-user23709-and-juniven)

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion of your question is not correct. You are right in whatever you have done. The set $B$ may not even be convex, so how can it be equal to co($A$)?

Comment: That's what I asked for another direction. If I prove that B is convex, would it be subset of $co(A)$?

Comment: Actually, no. There are a number of convex subsets containing $A$ and co($A$) is the smallest of them. So even if $B$ is convex, your conclusion is false.

Comment: So, you want to say that this Theorem is wrong? Even if I tell you that I have proof, but I don't understand it?

Comment: @user23709 Do tell me the proof. Take two points in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Then is the convex hull of two points the whole of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$?

Comment: http://www.econ.brown.edu/fac/Mark_Dean/Maths_CA1_10.pdf Page 3, Theorem 1

Comment: @user23709 If you look carefully, that statement and the statement you made in your question are not the same.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: Your set $B$ is any set containing all the convex combinations of $A$. In the notes, $B$ is exactly equal to the set of all convex combinations of $A$.

Comment: Probably you mean $B$ to be exactly equal to the set of all convex combinations of the elements of $A$. If so, do you understand the proof?

Comment: Yes, I meant that, but I still don't understand what I asked about, that is why $B\subset co(A)$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9198/discussion-between-vishal-and-user23709)